# Unnest key value pairs from json object

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I have a map with multiple key value pairs and I want to unnest them into separate rows.

```
"dayValueMap": {
    "2022-06-01": 1,
    "2022-06-02": 1,
    "2022-06-03": 1,
    "2022-06-04": 1,
    "2022-06-05": 1,
    "2022-06-06": 1,
}
```

I tried `JSON_EXTRACT` but that only extracts json from particular schema. Here I need to convert these key values as separate rows and in the map keys are dynamic.

Can someone help?

Comment: Into row in what table? Do all the json document look like this one?

Comment: I would be tempted to read these into a program and then fiddle with the json in that and then create the new rows from there

Comment: If you manage to upgrade your MySQL version, you can do something to solve this problem in a relatively smooth way. As is now, solutions (if any) would be fairly complex.

Comment: Provide sample source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Add desired output as table-formatted text.

Comment: If you can't upgrade to MySQL 8.0, then I would suggest you not store your data as JSON. Store the key-value pairs as discrete values on individual rows.

Comment: This question is identical to the one you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75137315/extract-key-value-pairs-from-mysql-json

Comment: @lemon Can you share the solution with mysql 8.0?

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 you can use:

- [`JSON_KEYS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys): to extract the array of keys from "*$.dayValueMap*" path
- [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table): to generate a table containing your extracted keys, one per record
- [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract): to extract the value from your table, using the previously extracted keys

```
SELECT json_key, 
       JSON_EXTRACT(info, CONCAT('$.dayValueMap.', json_key)) AS json_value
FROM tab,
     JSON_TABLE(
         JSON_KEYS(info, '$.dayValueMap'), '$[*]' 
         COLUMNS(
             json_key JSON PATH '$'
         )
    ) t;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ugBeGb2mq9rjQFPEkXQkTX/0).